# Extract items from 1 huge cell in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, extract

I have a huge spreadsheet of PC's and the software that is installed on them.
Unfortunately the report lists all the software installed for a PC in one cell.

I need a formula or macro which will go through every piece of software in the cell and extract all software that contains the word *Microsoft* and put it in a new cell in the next column on the same row. It must do this for every item found so that each Microsoft product installed appears in separate cells on the 1 row.

I have tried various things but am not sure how to get it to output every instance. I'm assuming it needs some sort of array and loop but wouldn't have a clue how to do it.

If any further info is required, please let me know.
Your help would be greatly appreciated.

The software cell looks like this:

> "Adobe Flash Player 10 Plugin | 10.3.181.26"; "Adobe Flash Player 11 ActiveX 64-bit | 11.0.1.152"; "Adobe Reader 9.4.6 | 9.4.6"; "Altiris Deployment Agent | 1.0.0"; "BigFix Enterprise Client | 7.2.5.22"; "Citrix Access Gateway Plugin | 4.6.1.2700"; "Citrix Password Manager Plugin | 4.6.264.0"; "Citrix XenApp Web Plugin | 11.0.0.5357"; "Definition update for Microsoft Office 2010 (KB982726)"; "Intel(R) Graphics Media Accelerator Driver"; "JXplorer | 3.2.2"; "Java(TM) 6 Update 16 | 6.0.160"; "McAfee Agent | 4.5.0.1852"; "McAfee AntiSpyware Enterprise Module | 8.7.0.129"; "McAfee Encrypted USB Client | 1.5.0"; "McAfee VirusScan Enterprise | 8.7.0"; "Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile | 4.0.30319"; "Microsoft Application Virtualization Desktop Client | 4.6.0.1523"; "Microsoft Conferencing Add-in for Microsoft Office Outlook | 8.0.6362.187"; "Microsoft Office Communicator 2007 | 2.0.6362.189"; "Microsoft Office InfoPath MUI (English) 2010 | 14.0.4763.1000"; "Microsoft Office Live Meeting 2007 | 8.0.6362.187"; "Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2010 | 14.0.4763.1000"; "Microsoft Office Visio 2007 Service Pack 2 (SP2)"; "Microsoft Office Visio Professional 2007 | 12.0.6425.1000"; "Microsoft Save as PDF or XPS Add-in for 2007 Microsoft Office programs | 12.0.4518.1014"; "Microsoft Silverlight | 4.0.60831.0"; "Microsoft Sync Framework Runtime v1.0 (x86) | 1.0.1215.0"; "Microsoft Sync Framework Services v1.0 (x86) | 1.0.1215.0"; "Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Redistributable - KB2467175 | 8.0.51011"; "Microsoft

Comment: By the way, I want to output the data into the cell looking like this: Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2010 | 14.0.4763.1000

Comment: What is the number of software items in the cell, would you say? Enough to fit within the total number of columns in Excel if the cell was broken apart?

Comment: I'd forgotten that Excel 2010 has over 16,000 columns. What you want can be done easily using the built-in commands on the Ribbon, but I take it you'd prefer an automatic solution?

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I would say there is probably about 50 items each PC would installed so definately enough columns hehe. Yes I need an automatic solution as its for thousands of PC's.

Answer (score 3):

This should do the job, just replace the worksheet and the range:

```
Sub ExtractSoftware()
    Dim ws as Worksheet    
    Dim lngRow As Long
    Dim rngSource As Range
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim varElement As Variant

    Set ws = Sheets("YourSheet")
    For lngRow = 1 To ws.Range("A1000000").End(xlUp).Row
        Set rngSource = ws.Cells(lngRow, 1)
        Set rng = rngSource.Offset(, 1)

        For Each varElement In Split(rngSource.Value, ";")
            If InStr(varElement, "Microsoft") Then
                varElement = Trim(varElement)
                rng.Value = Mid(varElement, 2, Len(varElement) - 2)
                Set rng = rng.Offset(, 1)
            End If
        Next varElement
    Next lngRow

End Sub
```

Comment: This is a good start, but returns all items, not just Microsoft items.

Comment: Oh, oversaw the filtering for MS. I changed the answer.

Comment: I think your original comment about text to columns combined with a find formula is a more flexible solution.

Comment: @Pynner: As Ani Mohr already provided the full solution to this approach, I wanted to provide the VBA approach, which does the job faster - and can also be flexible (but then requiring some changes in the code)

Comment: Good to have both options. If you do this kind of thing on a regular basis (lucky me, I do) just doing a series of find and replaces becomes second nature. But the VBA route is a good nuclear option for when things get really messy :)

Comment: Sorry mate ive been very busy and didnt have a chance to check for answers. I will give this a try and see how we go. Your effors are greatly appreciated, cant believe there are stll so many nice ppl around.

Comment: Ive tried this solution with my Sheet called Sheet 1 but nothing happened. I then changed the range to the range of the column that has all the software info in it, but again nothing happened in Excel.

Comment: Ive tried this solution with my Sheet called Sheet 1 but nothing happened. I then changed the range to the range of the column that has all the software info in it, but again nothing happened in Excel. Is the range my whole sheet which has data in it or just the column with the software info. Im also not sure where it would output the data.

Comment: @Michael: There were two references to the worksheet in the code - I modified it, so you now only need to change the name of your sheet in the first `Set` statement and the range. Then it should hopefully work.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use a combination of `Find and Replace`, and `Text to Columns`.

1. Copy the column in question to the end of the row. We're going to replace some of the data, so doing this in a 2nd column avoids losing your data if you make a mistake. (Belt and braces!)
2. Use the `Find and Replace` function to replace all instances of **Microsoft** with two special characters that won't be found elsewhere in this column. I often use **¬** and **`** as they are rarely used, so you're replacing **Microsoft** with **¬`**.
3. Now use the `Text to Columns` function on the data tab. Set your delimiter as your first special character: **¬**. This should now give you cells prefixed with Microsoft items. However, you also have a lot of other stuff following it.
4. To remove this extraneous stuff, select all the columns containing this info and do another `Find and Replace`. Find this: **;*** and replace with nothing (keep the textbox empty). This should strip out anything non-Microsoft that you don't want.
5. Finally you can re-add your label Microsoft by doing a `Find and Replace` on **`** and changing it back to **Microsoft**.
6. You may have some outstanding trailing **"** signs. Use another `Find and Replace` to remove them.

Once you get used to hacking info around like this you can do it very quickly, believe me!

Comment: Though in most cases, you probably need to delete the first column...

Comment: Yep, quite often!

Comment: Sorry mate ive been very busy and didnt have a chance to check for answers. I will give this a try and see how we go. Your effors are greatly appreciated, cant believe there are stll so many nice ppl around.

Comment: This is a very good solution, thank you. I will use this one for now but the VBA solution will also be useful for when I need to do this for hundreds of other reports for different products. Thanks again